# Assign a custom ringtone to a group in android

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, android-broadcast

I know how to assign custom ringtone to specific contact, but I want to set custom ringtone to a particular group. So that, when incoming call from any number belonging to that particular group my custom ringtone should be played.